# Elastic Search Query Filter and Sort for Date

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-query

Suppose each day 100 (some arbitrary number) records are getting indexed daily in elastic with a field as rundate. Now, when querying the elastic can we form a elastic query which results the latest runDate data.

For example:

all records are under one index.

{"runDate":"11:04:2020" .....} {"runDate":"11:04:2020" .....} .. * 100 records similarly.

{"runDate":"12:04:2020"......} {"runDate":"12:04:2020"......} .. * 150 records similarly.

Query Should return.

{"runDate":"12:04:2020"......} {"runDate":"12:04:2020"......} .. * 150 records similarly.

One solution/ Two query based.

1. Get the latest date by applying sort and size = 1 (Return 12:04:2020).
2. Apply match query for the date (12:04:2020) from step 1.

Can we do it better in just one query.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

**1. If you know the number of records you can use single query.**

Sort on rundate and fetch n records

```
GET <indexname>/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 3,  --> n records
  "sort": [
    {
      "runDate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**2. If you are trying to fetch records greater than current date**

```
GET <indexname>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "runDate": {
        "gte": "now/d" --> now-1d/d from yesterday, other calculations are available
      }
    }
  }, 
  "from": 0,
  "size": 3, 
  "sort": [
    {
      "runDate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**3. Get max date and use it to query for that date**

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "max_date": {
      "max": {
        "field": "runDate"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. Would be an arbitrary number so wouldn't be able to do so. 2. We need size here as well else it'll return response of 2-3 days and then we need segregate as well. 3. It'll we a two query approach.

Comment: In 3rd can we do something like filter on the basis of maxDate ?

Comment: You will need to input some date. This will require two queries  or you need to change index. Create a single document per date(nested)